# For a Charfield with choices, how to use the human readable name in list_display through a foreignkey?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

Let's assume I have the following :

**models.py :**

```
VALUE_CHOICES = (('0', 'ZERO'),
                 ('1', 'ONE'))

class ModelA(models.Model):
    def val(self):
        return self.model_b.value or ''

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, related_name="model_b", null=False)
    value = models.CharField(choices = VALUE_CHOICES)
```

and

**admin.py :**

```
class ModelAAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['val']
```

When I try to display my `ModelA` list in the admin site it displays `0` or `1` and not `ZERO` or `ONE`.

How could I modify this to make it display the human readable name from `VALUE_CHOICES` in the list from the admin site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display), and for the field `val`,

```
class ModelAAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['get_val_display']
```

This should do the job.

[**EDIT by OP**]
I didn't succeed to make it work like this but this kind of method was a really good suggestion. Here is how I used this `get_FOO_display()` method (and it worked like a charm).

I only modified my `ModelA.val()` method :

```
def val(self):
    return self.model_b.get_value_display()
```

Comment: @vmonteco sorry my bad. I thougt  `val`  is a regular field. Didn't notice that it is a method :)

Comment: No problem! the get_foo_display() was the only thing I really needed. I also tried with `list_display = ['movel_b__get_value_display']` though but it didn't work either. :)

Comment: `list_display = ['model_b__get_value_display']`* sorry